# How can I use a python string as input for my langchain loader?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, langchain

I want to have similarity search for a bunch of knowledge bases of mine and want to achieve that with langchain. As I need to retrieve the knowledge base from a database, I have all the content inside a python string, which I want to use as input for my loader.
My current code lokes like this:

```
from langchain.document_loaders import TextLoader
from langchain.indexes import VectorstoreIndexCreator

loader = TextLoader("./temp.txt", autodetect_encoding=True)
index = VectorstoreIndexCreator().from_loaders([loader])
```

How can I directly use the string as an input to avoid having to first write it to a TextFile.

I wasn't able to find anything on this in their documentation.

Comment: Don't think there is a way, but you can have a function that will make it easy to do. Would that be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually create a `Document` object

```py
from langchain.docstore.document import Document

docs =  Document(page_content="YOUR_STRING")
```

Then pass it to `VectorstoreIndexCreator`

```py
from langchain.indexes import VectorstoreIndexCreator
index = VectorstoreIndexCreator().from_documents([docs])
```